# What does it mean to say an ordered pair of vectors of random variables is independent of one anotehr

Tags: linear-algebra, probability

Suppose we are given i.i.d. random observations $\{ y_i,{\bf x_i} \}$ where $y$ is scalar and $\bf x$ is a vector. When one say  $\{ y_i,{\bf x_i} \}$ and  $\{ y_j,{\bf x_j} \}$ are independent of one another , what do they mean? Note that the definition of independence between random variables is

$$
F_{Y,\bf X}(\{ y_i,{\bf x_i} \},\{ y_j,{\bf x_j }\})=F(\{ y_i,{\bf x_i} \})\cdot F(\{ y_j,{\bf x_j} \}).
$$

where $F_{Y,\bf X}$ is the cumulative probability density function (suppose they are continuous). However, when we have ordered pairs including scalars and vectors, I find it hard to talk about cumulative probability, it seems to me that a more general definition of cumulative probability density function and independence criteria is needed. Help is appreciated, references are also wonderful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is similar. $(Y_i, \mathbf{X}_i)$ and $(Y_j, \mathbf{X}_j)$ are independent if and only if
$$ \Pr\{(Y_i, \mathbf{X}_i) \in A_i, (Y_j, \mathbf{X}_j) \in A_j\} = \Pr\{(Y_i, \mathbf{X}_i) \in A_i\}\Pr\{(Y_j, \mathbf{X}_j) \in A_j\}$$

for all $A_i, A_j \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{k+1}$. See, e.g.

http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4615-7676-1_12

Comment: You mean $A_i,A_j\subset \mathbb{R}^{k+1}$, right?

Comment: Can you recommend another book please? My college does not subscribe to the Springer Library..

Comment: Yes my typo. Should have other reference https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)#For_random_variables; and there is a preview in that link which briefly talk about that.